# ESLint が vite.config.ts に対し strictNullChecks が有効化されていないというエラーを出す

Tags: typescript, eslint

`yarn create vite` で React かつ TypeScript + RSC なプロジェクトを作った後、README.md にしたがって ESLint の設定を増やしたところ、`yarn lint` で以下のエラーが消せませんでした。

```
/path/to/my-project/vite.config.ts
  0:1  error  This rule requires the `strictNullChecks` compiler option to be turned on to function correctly  @typescript-eslint/prefer-nullish-coalescing
  0:1  error  This rule requires the `strictNullChecks` compiler option to be turned on to function correctly  @typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-condition
```

エラーメッセージには `strictNullChecks` を有効にせよと書かれているのですが、tsconfig.json を見ると `strict: true` になっています。なぜこのエラーが出るのでしょうか。

以下詳細な環境情報です。

### package.json

```js
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.0.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc": "^3.3.2",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.3",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "vite": "^4.4.5"
  },
  "volta": {
    "node": "18.17.1",
    "yarn": "1.22.19"
  },
  "packageManager": "yarn@3.6.3"
}
```

### tsconfig.json

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

### .eslintrc.cjs

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: { browser: true, es2020: true },
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: '2020',
    sourceType: 'module',
    project: ['./tsconfig.json', './tsconfig.node.json'],
    tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
  },
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/strict-type-checked',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/stylistic-type-checked',
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'plugin:react/jsx-runtime',
    'plugin:react-hooks/recommended',
  ],
  ignorePatterns: ['dist', '.eslintrc.cjs'],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  plugins: ['react-refresh'],
  rules: {
    'react-refresh/only-export-components': [
      'warn',
      { allowConstantExport: true },
    ],
  },
  settings: {
    react: {
      version: 'detect',
    },
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

自己回答です。tsconfig.node.json で `strict: true` になっていませんでした。設定を追加したところ解決しました。

Vite 4.4 では、https://stackoverflow.com/q/72027949/5989200 で解説されているように tsconfig.json と tsconfig.node.json のふたつの設定が存在します。このうち vite.config.ts の設定として使われるのは tsconfig.node.json であるため、こちらに `strictNullChecks: true` が必要です。`strict: true` は `strictNullChecks: true` を含意するので `strict: true` でも大丈夫です。

↓修正前の tsconfig.node.json

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": ["vite.config.ts"]
}
```

// VS Code で編集している場合で、tsconfig.node.json を編集してもエディタ上の ESLint の警告が消えない場合は、VS Code を再起動して ESLint Server を再起動させると良いです。